# What do the Stream reduce() requirements exactly entail?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, reduce

When using the `reduce()` operation on a parallel stream, [the OCP exam book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ocp-oracle-certified/9781119067900/) states that there are certain principles the `reduce()` arguments must adhere to. Those principles are the following:

> 1. The identity must be defined such that for all elements in the stream u, combiner.apply(identity, u) is equal to u.
> 2. The accumulator operator op must be associative and stateless such that `(a op b) op c` is equal to `a op (b op c)`.
> 3. The combiner operator must also be associative and stateless and compatible with the identity, such that for all of `u` and `t` `combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t))` is equal to `accumulator.apply(u,t)` .

The book gives two examples to illustrate these principles, please see the code below:

example for associative:

```
System.out.println(
        Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
                .parallelStream()
                .reduce(0, (a, b) -> (a - b)));
```

What the book says about this:

> It may output -21, 3, or some other value as the accumulator function
>   violates the associativity property.

example for the identity requirement:

```
System.out.println(
        Arrays.asList("w", "o", "l", "f")
                .parallelStream()
                .reduce("X", String::concat));
```

What the book says about this:

> You can see other problems if we use an identity parameter that is not
>   truly an identity value. It can output `XwXoXlXf`. As part of the
>   parallel process, the identity is applied to multiple elements in the
>   stream, resulting in very unexpected data.

I don't understand those examples. With the accumulator example the accumulator starts with `0 - 1` which is `-1`, then `-1 - 2` which is `-3`, then `-6` etc all the way to `-21`. I understand that, because the generated arraylist isn't synchronized the results maybe be unpredictable because of the possibility of race conditions etc, but why isn't the accumulator associative? Wouldn't `(a+b)` cause unpredictable results too? I really don't see what's wrong with the accumulator being used in the example and why it's not associative, but then again I still don't exactly understand what "associative principle" means.

I don't understand the identity example either. I understand that the result could indeed be `XwXoXlXf` if 4 separate threads were to start accumulating with the identity at the same time, but what does that have to do with the identity parameter itself? What exactly would be a proper identity to use then?

I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me a bit more on these principles.

Thank you

Comment: It’s all in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity): “**Associativity**  
An operator or function `op` is associative if the following holds:
    `(a op b) op c == a op (b op c)` 
The importance of this to parallel evaluation can be seen if we expand this to four terms:
     `a op b op c op d == (a op b) op (c op d)`
So we can evaluate `(a op b)` in parallel with `(c op d)`, and then invoke `op` on the results.” For examples of valid identity values, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32867283/2711488)

Comment: It should be emphasized that the nature of the source `List` is *not* an issue; there is no need to have a synchronized list for a parallel stream. You must not modify the source list while the operation is ongoing, but that applies to sequential streams as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me give two examples. First where the identity is broken:

```
int result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        .parallel()
        .reduce(10, (a, b) -> a + b);

System.out.println(result); // 81 on my run
```

Basically you have broken this rule: `The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function.  This means that for all u, accumulator(identity, u) is equal to u`.

Or to make is simpler, let's see if that rule holds for some random data from our Stream:

```
 Integer identity = 10;
 BinaryOperator<Integer> combiner = (x, y) -> x + y;
 boolean identityRespected = combiner.apply(identity, 1) == 1;
 System.out.println(identityRespected); // prints false
```

And a second example:

```
/**
 * count letters, adding a bit more all the time
 */
private static int howMany(List<String> tokens) {
    return tokens.stream()
            .parallel()
            .reduce(0, // identity
                    (i, s) -> { // accumulator
                        return s.length() + i;
                    }, (left, right) -> { // combiner
                        return left + right + left; // notice the extra left here
                    });
}
```

And you invoke this with:

```
List<String> left = Arrays.asList("aa", "bbb", "cccc", "ddddd", "eeeeee");
List<String> right = Arrays.asList("aa", "bbb", "cccc", "ddddd", "eeeeee", "");

System.out.println(howMany(left));  // 38 on my run
System.out.println(howMany(right)); // 50 on my run
```

Basically you have broken this rule: `Additionally, the combiner function must be compatible with the accumulator function` or in code :

```
// this must hold!
// combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)

Integer identity = 0;
String t = "aa";
Integer u = 3; // "bbb"
BiFunction<Integer, String, Integer> accumulator = (Integer i, String s) -> i + s.length();
BinaryOperator<Integer> combiner = (left, right) -> left + right + left;

int first = accumulator.apply(identity, t); // 2
int second = combiner.apply(u, first); // 3 + 2 + 3 = 8

Integer shouldBe8 = accumulator.apply(u, t);

System.out.println(shouldBe8 == second); // false
```

Comment: *"The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function.  This means that for all u, accumulator(identity, u) is equal to u."*, **it's not accumulator function, it's combiner function**.

Comment: @JasonLaw the cite is correct. It’s exactly as written in the documentation of `reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`, which has been used in the first example. This method doesn’t even have a *combiner* function. Don’t confuse with the method `reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`.

Answer (score 10):

> why isn't the accumulator associative?

It's not associative since the order of subtraction operations determines the final result.

If you run a serial `Stream`, you'll get the expected result of:

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 = -21
```

On the other hand, for parallel `Stream`s, the work is split to multiple threads. For example, if `reduce` is executed in parallel on 6 threads, and then the intermediate results are combined, you can get a different result:

```
0 - 1   0 - 2   0 - 3      0 - 4     0 - 5    0 - 6
  -1     -2      -3         -4        -5        -6

  -1 - (-2)         -3 - (-4)          -5 - (-6)
      1                 1                  1
           1   -   1
               0            -     1

                        -1
```

Or, to make a long example short:

```
(1 - 2) - 3 = -4
1 - (2 - 3) =  2
```

Therefore subtraction is not associative.

On the other hand, `a+b` doesn't cause the same problem, since addition is an associative operator (i.e. `(a+b)+c == a+(b+c)`).

The problem with the identity example is that when reduce is executed in parallel on multiple threads, "X" is appended to the starts of each intermediate result.

> What exactly would be a proper identity to use then?

If you change the identity value to `""` :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("w","o","l","f"))
.parallelStream()
.reduce("", String::concat));
```

you'll get "wolf" instead of "XwXoXlXf".

Comment: how can we know the number of thread that steam parallel  processing will create.
It is a fix value of depends on the collection size

Comment: @Hasnain I don't know. That's an implementation detail.

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra - I would actually say "we **cannot** know" because it is an unspecified implementation detail, and there are no APIs to find out.

Comment: "since addition is an associative operator" AFAIK only for integers

Answer (score 5):

While the question has already been answered and accepted, I think it can be answered in a simpler, more practical way.

If you don't have a valid `identity` and an associative accumulator/combiner, the result of the `reduce` operation will depend on:

1. the `Stream` content
2. the number of threads processing the `Stream`

## Associativity

Let's try with an example for non-associative  accumulator/combiner (basically, we reduce a list of 50 numbers in a sequence and in parallel by varying the number of threads):

```
System.out.println("sequential: reduce="+
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 50).boxed()
        .reduce(
            0, 
            (a,b)->a-b, 
            (a,b)->a-b));
for (int n=1; n<6; n++) {
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(n);
    final int finalN = n;
    try {
        pool.submit(()->{
            System.out.println(finalN+" threads : reduce="+
                IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 50).boxed()
                    .parallel()
                    .reduce(
                        0, 
                        (a,b)->a-b, 
                        (a,b)->a-b));
            }).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            pool.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

This displays the following results (Oracle JDK 10.0.1) :

```
sequential: reduce=-1275
1 threads : reduce=325
2 threads : reduce=-175
3 threads : reduce=-25
4 threads : reduce=75
5 threads : reduce=-25
```

This shows that the result depends on the number of threads involved in the reduce calculation.

Notes:

- Interestingly, sequential reduce and parallel reduce for one thread do not lead to the same result. I could not find a good explanation.
- From my experiments, the same `Stream` content and the same number of threads always leads to the same reduced value when ran several times. I suppose this is because the parallel stream uses a deterministic `Spliterator`.
- I would not use Boyarsky&Selikoff OCP8 book example because the stream is too small (1,2,3,4,5,6) and produces (on my machine) the same reduce value of 3 for a `ForkJoinPool` of 1,2,3,4 or 5 threads.
- the default number of threads for a parallel stream is the number of availables CPU cores. This is why you may not have the same reduce result on every machine.

## Identity

For `identity`, as Eran wrote with the "XwXoXlXf" example, with 4 threads, each thread will start by using the `identity` as a kind of `String` prefix. But pay attention : while the OCP book suggests that `""` and `0` are valid `identity`, it depends on the accumulator/combiner functions. For example:

- `0` is a valid `identity` for accumulator `(a,b)->a+b` (because `a+0=a`)
- `1` is a valid `identity` for accumulator `(a,b)->a*b` (because `a*1=a`, but `0` is not valid because `a*0=0`!)

Answer (score 2):

Reduction of a **sequential stream** looks as follows: sequentially applying a reduction *function* to each pair of elements of a stream, expecting to receive at each step an element of a same type as other elements of the stream. At next step applying the same *function* again, and so on.

```
a   b   c   d   e
│   │   │   │   │
└─┬─┘   │   │   │
 a+b    │   │   │   a+b=sum1
  │     │   │   │
  └──┬──┘   │   │
  sum1+c    │   │   sum1+c=sum2
     │      │   │
     └──┬───┘   │
     sum2+d     │   sum2+d=sum3
        │       │
        └──┬────┘
        sum3+e      sum3+e=total;
```

Reduction of a **parallel stream** has the same expectancy, but gives no guarantee which pair of elements (or their sums from previous steps) should be captured at next step. Thus, the result may vary.

```
a   b   c   d   e
│   │   │   │   │
└─┬─┘   └─┬─┘   │
 a+b     c+d    │   a+b=sum1   c+d=sum2

or:
    │   │   │   │
    └─┬─┘   └─┬─┘
     b+c     d+e    b+c=sum1   d+e=sum2

  │       │     │
  └───┬───┘     │
  sum1+sum2     │   sum..+sum..=sum..

or:

│     │   │     │
└──┬──┘   └──┬──┘
 a+sum1    sum2+e   sum..+sum..=sum..
```

---

<sup>See also: [Generate all possible string combinations by replacing the hidden “#” number sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65975106/14940971)</sup>