# why Combiner is not making affect on output?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The following code output is 24 all the time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("java");
    list.add("php");
    list.add("python");
    list.add("perl");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("lisp");
    list.add("c#");
    int s = list.stream().reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y.length(), (x, y) -> 0);
    System.out.println(s);
    s = list.stream().reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y.length(), (x, y) -> x - y);
    System.out.println(s);
    s = list.stream().reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y.length(), (x, y) -> x * y);
    System.out.println(s);

}
```

Question is why combiner is effecting my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

combiner is *only* used for parallel streams.

But there might be other problems with your code even if you add `parallel`. They all violate some rules... Specifically:

> Additionally, the combiner function must be compatible with  the accumulator function; for all u and t, the following must hold

```
 combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)
```

And your combiners violate this, so depending on the number of CPU's you have - you will get different results - which is obviously wrong.

Comment: can you explain more about **combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)** ??

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054372/what-do-the-stream-reduce-requirements-exactly-entail/45054892#45054892

Comment: Thanks i was having same doubt form the same OCJP book.Im asking about the sentence>>Means what is u and what the expression **combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t))**  is

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra `u` and `t` would be two random elements from the stream (*any two elements*); and the `accumulator` and `combiner` are the second and third parameter of your `reduce`

Comment: thanks u deserve upvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150281/discussion-between-hasnain-ali-bohra-and-eugene).

Answer (score 2):

`combiner` would affect the result if you reduce parallel `Stream`. For a sequential `Stream` there is no need to combine partial results.

For example, when I change `stream()` to `parallelStream()` in you code, I get:

```
0
6
2304
```

Of course, all the combiners you supplied are bad combiners. You should supply a combiner that **doesn't** affect the final result of `reduce`.

Comment: don't you love this? when you know you are right and still get a down vote? :)