# How to make stream reduce be thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

Java stream API offers a general `.reduce(identity, accumulator)` method.

It is pretty clear from javadocs that accumulator should be a stateless function.

However, I have a question about the `identity` object, namely should it be thread-safe?

Lets say an `identity` is a java object and an `accumulator` modifies that object in a way that the modification is not atomic, e.g. `accumulator` looks into `identity's` state and then decides how to modify it's internal state exactly. Clearly it can happen that several reduce operations may run at the same time. In this case several questions arise:

- should this one reduce operation be atomic in the scope of the `identity` object?
- is it enough just to make `identity` object immutable and return a new instance upon each reduce?

Comment: consider using the overload with an additional combiner instead.

Comment: If you want to always be threadsafe then you can use the multi-args`collect()` or call the single-args method with `Collector.of()` (or even your own `Collector` implementation). That way you can have multiple "identities" which all get merged together at the end in a thread safe manner

Comment: Another way would be to always return a new identity. I.e. create a new instance, copy the old values over, modify the state of the new instance and return said instance

Comment: Also worth a read: [Parallel streams, collectors and thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350288/parallel-streams-collectors-and-thread-safety)

Comment: If `accumulator` modifies `identity`, then `identity` is part of the state of `accumulator`. As such, `accumulator` isn't stateless.

Comment: The `accumulator` should not modify *any* of its incoming arguments. This also solves the issue that the accumulator does not know whether or which of its arguments are identity values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ordinarily, `accumulator` is an english word that means: "You are completely hosed if you want parallelism". It's right there in the word: To accumulate - to gather over time. There is no way to do it right except to start from the beginning, and apply accumulation until you are done.

But, java gets around this by adding 2 requirements:

1. associativity. `a X (b X c)` must produce the same result as `(a X b) X c`, where X is the accumulator function.
2. identity function. `ident X a` must be equal to `a`, where `ident` is the identity you pass to `reduce` and X is the accumulator function.

Let's use as example the function `(a, b) -> a + b` and as identity `0`, which fulfills both of these requirements if your intent is to sum a list.

Java can parallellize this by just summing arbitrary terms and then summing the results of these. `[1, 5, 9, 12]` can be summed by first lopping the list into two, then handing these 2 sublists to threads to individually sum, and then summing the answers each thread provides. **This implies that java will start accumulation multiple times at arbitrary points in the stream, and will apply identity as part of its accumulation any number of times, at arbitrary points**, and that brings swift problems if your identity object is itself mutable.

There's basically no way to combine the notion of a mutable `identity` object and java's `reduce` function. It is fundamentally not designed to work that way.

Contrast to the sum example: Instead of modifying a in the `(a, b) -> a + b` accumulator, neither a nor b are modified; instead, they are combined into a newly created third value, and that's how you should use this method.

Contrast to `foldLeft` from certain other languages, which do not require either `accumulatorFunction(ident, A)` to be equal to A, nor associativity, but then cannot by definition parallellize it, at all. That foldLeft *can* be used with mutable state. For example, here is an impl of summing using a foldLeft, in pseudocode: (note that `new int[1]` is used here as mutable integer):

```
int sum = stream.foldLeft(new int[1], (int[] a, int b) -> a[0] += b)[0];
```

This notion (where the LHS of your accumulator function is always the same thing, namely, your identity object, being modified to integrate each value in the stream as you move along it) is **not compatible** with java's reduce, and as far as I can recall, java has no (easy) way to do this kind of thing to a stream.

Thus: It's worse! 'thread safe' isn't good enough, it needs to be immutable. Once it is immutable, it is trivially thread safe.

> is it enough just to make identity object immutable and return a new instance upon each reduce?

That's not just 'good enough', that's more or less the only sane way to use `reduce`.

Comment: You should not use the term “identity object” in the context of foldLeft. Besides that, `collect(() -> new int[1], (a,b) -> a[0] += b, (a1,a2) -> a1[0] += a2[0])[0]` is not so much harder…

Comment: @rzwitserloot - The term _assumulator_ is new to me, but it's an interesting innovation, I assume. ;-)

Comment: Oh, that's one of my more inspired typo's :) thanks for letting me know, I'll edit this answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is covered by the documentation, but not directly, it is implied.

> The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function. **This means that for all t, accumulator.apply(identity, t) is equal to t**.

As soon as `identity` is modified, like you say, even if in a thread-safe way, the rule above is violated; thus no guarantees of the expected result.

For the second question the answer is slightly more involved. You do not *have* to make the `identity` immutable, as long as no one abuses that (by modifying its internal state). Of course making it `immutable` helps a lot in that regard.

Comment: One of your earlier answers that could relate and explain with example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054372/what-do-the-stream-reduce-requirements-exactly-entail