# Stream.reduce() vs Stream.parallel.reduce()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I really want to know the exact difference between `Stream.reduce() and Stream.parallel.reduce()`

To clear everything I created a small program and found that result is not equal with same values .

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> i * 10).reduce(5, (abc, cde) -> abc + cde);
        int b = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> i * 10).
        parallel().reduce(5, (abc, cde) -> abc + cde);
        System.out.println(a == b) //False;
    }
}
```

So, does this means that they both are different if so please help me understand how they are different in functionality wise ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32867283/2711488

Answer (score 11):

It seem that you are misusing the `reduce` function. When using `reduce` with an identity value, you have to make sure the identity corresponds to an identity on the associative reduce function.

See the full [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html), and a good explanation of what `reduce` does [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). The `reduce` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) says:

> The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function.
> This means that for all `t`, `accumulator.apply(identity, t)` is equal to `t`.
> The accumulator function must be an associative function.

In your case, `5` is not the identity of the `+` function you are using for reducing, thus leading to strange results when using parallel reduces. `0` is the identity of addition, so a correct way to compute would be to add `5` to the list, and use `reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y))`.
Additionally, since you are reducing a stream of `int` to an `int`, you can simply use `reduce((x, y) -> x + y)`.

The reason is that parallel reduce uses the information that identity is a mathematical identity to optimize for parallel execution. In your case, it will inject multiple `identity`values in the computation.

Comment: Thanks for the information, so this means they are not same functions

Comment: No, they are the same method. Read the last paragraph of the answer. ---- The linear case starts with 5, adds 10, add 20, adds 30, ends up with **65**. ---- In the parallel case, it might split the numbers into [1, 2] and [3]. So now it starts with 5, add 10, adds 20; and in parallel starts with 5, adds 30. Now it sums up the sub results of 35 and 35, ends up with **70**. ---- When using reduce with two parameters, the first one has to have no effect in the reduce function, especially when using parallel. But 5 **does** have an effect when using `+`.

Comment: In principle, it would also be legal for a stream to just return the sum of all elements when you say `reduce(5, (x,y) -> x+y)`, without ever adding `5` to it. Even for a sequential stream.