# Streams reduce question on partial results

Tags: java

I understand function (b) below, however am having confusion with (a).  Can anyone explain what the accumulator or second argument to `reduce` or accumulator is doing vs the combiner parameter?

a:

```
   reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)

double productOfSqrRoots = myList.stream().reduce(
    1.0,
    (a,b) -> a * Math.sqrt(b),
    (a,b) -> a * b
    );
```

b:

```
double productOfSqrRoots = myList.stream().reduce(
    (a,b) -> a * b);
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970149/how-does-the-reduce-method-work-in-java-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start at the top. According to [`java.util.stream.Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), there are three overloads of `reduce` to consider.

- `T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`
- `Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`
- `<U> U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`

## Two-argument reduce

The first one is arguably the simplest, and it's the one that a functional programmer would be most familiar with. This function would be called `foldl` in Haskell, `reduce` in Python, `inject` in Ruby, etc.

Let's assume that `myStream` contains the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4`. Then `myStream.reduce(e, (x, y) -> x # y)` (where `#` is some arbitrary binary operation and `e` is our identity value) would perform

```
(((e # 1) # 2) # 3) # 4
```

That is, we start with the identity, and then we apply the binary operator to the accumulated value so far and the next element of the stream, for each element, until the stream is exhausted. This is a typical functional-programming fold/reduce operation.

## One-argument reduce

The second form of `reduce` eschews the `identity` argument in favor of just bailing out and returning an `Optional<T>`. So if our stream consisted of the same `1, 2, 3, 4`, then `myStream.reduce((x, y) -> x # y)` would give

```
Optional.of(((1 # 2) # 3) # 4)
```

We don't have an identity `0` in there. Instead, we got an `Optional` that contained a value. Empty streams would simply give `Optional.empty()`, rather than producing the `identity` as the two-argument form would.

## Three-argument reduce

Everything so far has been fairly typical functional programming fare. But here's where Java's implementation differs. Java's `reduce` is built with concurrency in mind, and the three-argument reduce is where this shows.

As a reminder, `myStream.reduce(e, (x, y) -> x # y)` (where, again, `#` is some arbitrary binary operator), looks like

```
(((e # 1) # 2) # 3) # 4
```

Then, in turn, `myStream.reduce(e, (x, y) -> x # y, (x, y) -> x $ y)` looks like

```
(((e $ (e # 1)) $ (e # 2)) $ (e # 3)) $ (e # 4)
```

That looks... complicated, needless to say. The `reduce` function requires that, if `e` is our identity, then `$` satisfies

```
x $ (e # y) == x # y
```

for all `x` and `y` in our domain. That is, putting the `e` bit on the left of `$` doesn't actually do anything. If we follow this rule, then the above complicated expression is just the same as applying 2-argument `reduce`. So why would we ever do this? Well, Java is permitted to run the `$` bits in parallel. Back when we had

```
(((e # 1) # 2) # 3) # 4
```

All of the `#` operations depended on the results of the previous `#` operations. There was no room for parallelism.

```
(((e $ (e # 1)) $ (e # 2)) $ (e # 3)) $ (e # 4)
```

Here, on the other hand, each of the `#` operations is independent and doesn't depend on *any* of the other calls. So we could parallelize all of the `#` calls and then combine the results with the combiner `$` in one thread. If `#` is expensive but `$` is cheap, this is a huge gain.

And in your example, `#` is a multiplication-and-square-root, which is probably more expensive than `$`, which is just a multiplication. So if we can come up with a `$` for our `#` which satisfies

```
x $ (e # y) == x # y
```

then we get parallelism gains. That is, this form of `reduce` is just forcing us to split our reduction calculation out into two parts: the "expensive" parallelizable bit and the actual combining bit which might be cheaper.

Now, all of that being said, the documentation has this to say.

> Many reductions using this form can be represented more simply by an explicit combination of map and reduce operations. The accumulator function acts as a fused mapper and accumulator, which can sometimes be more efficient than separate mapping and reduction, such as when knowing the previously reduced value allows you to avoid some computation.

And this is true. In your case, using three-argument reduce is just goofy, because what we're really doing is mapping and then reducing. So your example should really be written as

```
myList.stream().map((a) -> Math.sqrt(a)).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b)
```

This is what we're actually trying to say: square-root each value and *then* multiply them. Streams are lazy, so doing this in two steps doesn't create an intermediate list. It just remembers what needs to be done and then does it when forced by the reduction.

So three-argument reduce is for cases where we really can exploit known information about the partial results. Maybe our reduction operation is short-circuiting, and if the left-hand side has a certain value then we don't even need to *do* the mapping operation. Maybe there's a caching argument, and knowing previous results allows us to save some processing time in the future. Maybe there's some clever mathematical reduction not listed here.

Fusing the map and reduce operations like this is, at best, very situational. So generally you should prefer to use `map` followed by an associative `reduce` whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

The below functional code:

```java
myList.stream().reduce( 1.0, (a,b) -> a * Math.sqrt(b), (a,b) -> a * b);
```

is conceptually equivalent to:

```java
double sum = 1.0;
    for (Double value: myList){
        sum= sum * Math.sqrt(value);
}
```

Here,

The `U identity` is basically the initial value.

`BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator` is a BiFunction for incorporating an additional element into a result.

`BinaryOperator<U> combiner` for combining two values, which must be compatible with the accumulator function. The combiner function is used in parallel stream processing to combine the results of different substreams.

---

### What is Combiner Function used for?

> When a stream executes in parallel, the Java runtime splits the stream
> into multiple substreams. In such cases, we need to use a function to
> combine the results of the substreams into a single one. This is the
> role of the combiner.

### Why my Combiner Function Gets Ignored?

Since you are using **a sequential stream**, the combiner function is not actually used in this case.

### How can I Use Combiner Function Then?

If you change the combiner function in action, you can change combiner function to something like `Double:Sum` and use `parallel` stream rather than sequential stream.

Example:

```java
myList.stream().parallel.reduce( 1.0, (a,b) -> a * Math.sqrt(b), Double::sum );
```